# "Incompatible App" error with Google VR app

Tags: android, virtual-reality, google-vr, daydream

I've been working with the Google VR SDK and I wrote a simple app that uses the GvrActivity and GvrView. The app used to work without any issues, but after I started using the Daydream headset, the app won't run.

Instead, when I deploy the app with Android Studio, I get an "Incompatible App" message that says "This Cardboard application is not compatible with Daydream headsets."

I didn't make any changes to the app. Stereo mode and VR mode are disabled, so I don't know what the problem is. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by turning off Google VR Services. This can be done by going to Settings > Apps and selecting "Show System" in the menu. Then scroll down to "Google VR Services" and select "Disable". After this, regular apps can run normally.

Answer (score 2):

Place the phone in the View first and get the Daydream environment started before running the project from your IDE. This error occurs for me when I try and start it when the phone is on the home screen or another app, but putting it in the View beforehand gets it working.